# How to stop carousel onhover in SliderJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have no knowlege in JS so please help me with it. I have a slider (Slider JS) I need to make the slider to stop on hovering it and when the cursor is moved away it should resume again.

I refered this slidejs website which is [here](http://archive.slidesjs.com/) and i found this code which did not work form me

```
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slides({
    hoverPause: true
  });
});
```

Here is my JS code

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".slider_container").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: ".arrow_right",
            btnPrev: ".arrow_left",
            visible: 4,
            speed :1000,
            auto : 500,
            hoverPause: true,
        });
    });
```

Html

```
 <div id="slide_image_contener" class="slider_container">
   <ul id="slide">
      <li><a class="vlightbox1" href="popup/vlb_images1/certification_1.jpg" title="certification_1"><img src="popup/vlb_thumbnails1/certification_1.jpg" class="vlightbox_1" alt="certification_1"/></a></li>
       <li><a class="vlightbox1" href="popup/vlb_images1/certification_1.jpg" title="certification_1"><img src="popup/vlb_thumbnails1/certification_1.jpg" class="vlightbox_1" alt="certification_1"/></a></li>
        <li><a class="vlightbox1" href="popup/vlb_images1/certification_1.jpg" title="certification_1"><img src="popup/vlb_thumbnails1/certification_1.jpg" class="vlightbox_1" alt="certification_1"/></a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? It's working correctly at my end.

Comment: which version of slider you are using?

Comment: @wasimbhalli:hover pause is not working

Comment: just wondering what does `jCarouselLite` have to do here? i think you are using http://plugins.learningjquery.com/jcarousellite/ not `slider js`

Comment: @Zain Refer to my answer below

Comment: @Cerline Boss: Ok, then can u help me with the onhover event, I need the slider to be paused when mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in code.

Your JS is referring to `#slides`:

```
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slides({
    hoverPause: true
  });
});
```

**But** you are using ul `id="slide"`

Change this line: `<ul id="slide">` to this: `<ul id="slides">`

Comment: that code is which i took the hoverpause:true line to my js code which is below it. tats not my actual code

Comment: @Zain Either ways, the id has to be same. Change the ul id to "slides"

Comment: @Zain Try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The options which you are passing is wrong. You should pass `pause` instead of `hoverPause` Try the below code

```
jQuery(".slider_container").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".arrow_right",
    btnPrev: ".arrow_left",
    visible: 4,
    speed :1000,
    auto : 500,
    pause: true
});
```